# Android webview twitter timeline widget feed not updating

Tags: android, twitter, webview, widget

**I'm having difficulties to make webview automatically update the feed from twitter when it's available.**

Right now, it will show twitter timeline widget in webview without any problem. If I tweet a new message immediately after the timeline widget loads in webview (within 20-30 seconds), the twitter timeline widget will automatically update the new twitter feed. However, if I leave it idle for roughly 40seconds to 1 minute, and then tweet a new message, it'll never get updated anymore.

Here's code for my webview.

```
//***** Creating twitter webview *****
string webscript = "[TWITTER GENERATED WIDGET TIMELINE CODE GOES HERE]";

WebView wv = new WebView(this);

//***** Perform webview settings *****
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
wv.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
wv.getSettings().setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

/* !!!!! Dirty fix, but it's working !!!!! */
wv.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; U; CPU like Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/420+ (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/3.0 Mobile/1A543a Safari/419.3");

/***** Let's load data with base URL pointing to https://twitter.com *****/
wv.loadDataWithBaseURL("https://twitter.com", webscript, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```

Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I've end up solving this problem by clearing the WebView cache every now and then. It work after I do that.

Comment: could you tell he where did you cleared the cache exactly?